# How can I open port 3690 (svn) to my network?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, port

I've set up subversion about a year ago and have been using it with no problem, checking in files almost every day and updating them on another system on my network. For no apparent reason, it suddenly started giving me "connection refused" messages when I try to commit or update.

I've checked nmap and netstat and discovered that port 3690 is open on localhost only, but not the network. How can I force it to open that port to my whole network and not just its own localhost? And what could have caused it to suddenly close port 3690 to my network in the first place? I haven't changed anything on my system or my configuration.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this is not a computer support website. Your question must relate to programming.

Comment: Oh, I guess I should also mention that I did run svnserve -d and I ran ps -A and it shows that it is running, however the port is not open to the network.

Comment: @MattBall It is ubuntu.

Comment: If this is really just a networking configuration problem, not an SVN-specific one, this is probably a better question to ask at http://askubuntu.com.